# Creating collision shapes for Phaser

Tags: javascript, collision, game-physics, phaser-framework

I've been trying to create collision shapes out of a PNG file for Phaser in JSON format. PhysicsEditor is the only application I know. Unfortunately, OpenGL 2.0 is not supported by my graphics card(drivers are up to date). Are the any alternative programs or ways to make create these collision shapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [matter.js](http://brm.io/matter-js/) or [PhysicsJS](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/). Both of these tools have methods which can help you to build a world with shapes and catch collisions. You can extend this frameworks with custom renderers

Comment: Do you mean I should dump the P2 engine and use these instead?

Comment: Your engine supports collision detection too. You can get sample here: http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/one-way-collision. But there are many other framework for physics on JavaScript. (two of them in my answer).